# localStorage updates between pages; works in FF 39.0 & Chrome 44, but not in Safari 8.0

Tags: javascript, html, safari, local-storage

I've created an offline site consisting of 2 .html pages and 1 underlying .js page with the necessary functions (both html pages reference this js page):

1) **edit.html** is where an array of values is entered by the user in a simple html form and, upon Submit, stored in a JSON stringify-d localStorage variable (`"personList"`). The script then does `window.location.href = "main.html";` which loads the other page.

2) **main.html** , in the `body onload` event, runs a function that first retrieves the localStorage variable `"personList"`.  If `"personList"` is undefined, it redirects the user back to **edit.html** to enter values; otherwise it does a JSON parse on `"personList"` to get it back into an array, populates several areas of the **main.html** page with the values.

This works fine in FF 39, Chrome 44, and Safari 8; on initial load of the **main.html** page, the values match what was entered in **edit.html**.

**Here's where the problem occurs:**

**main.html** has a link to allow the user to edit the list; the link simply does a `window.location.href = "edit.html"` to take the user back to that page.  **edit.html** populates the form with the values from localStorage variable `"personList"`, and the user can then update these values and hit Submit again (which then takes the user back to **main.html**).

- In FF 39, **main.html** displays the **updated** values from `"personList"` as expected

  - In Chrome 44, **main.html** displays the **updated** values from `"personList"` as expected
- In Safari 8, **main.html** displays the **pre-update** values of `"personList"`.

A check of the localStorage variable contents in Safari developer tools confirms that while **edit.html** value of `"personList"` is updated, **main.html** value appears to be cached (as it still contains the old content).

If I close the Safari window and then open a new window, it pulls the updated values of `"personList"`, but I obviously don't want the user to have to close and reopen the browser.  The function called in the `onLoad` event (that loads the values into **main.html**) is definitely being triggered both on initial load and when it comes from **edit.html**.

I've googled and searched stack and not finding this scenario - any ideas?

Comment: I'd still really like to hear from anyone who has solved this issue, but I've worked around it in my app by using a pop-up temporary div to get the values (rather than navigating to a different html page).  This approach seems to work in both FF & Safari, so good enough for now.

Comment: My question [javascript - Page not refreshed after localstorage update and navigatge back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938373/page-not-refreshed-after-localstorage-update-and-navigatge-back) is similar.